# Conditional rendering in radio button saves both values in the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, react-native, react-redux

I'm new to react, I have conditional rendering in radio button,

- lets say a ratio button has 2 options `option1` and `option2`
- on selection `option1` the page shows up 2 `text fields` ( say first and last name )
- on selection `option2` the page shows up 2 buttons`(say`btn1`and`btn2`)
- if i select `option1` and fill up `first & last name` and hit save, it saved and if i come back to this page, it shows last filled `first & last name`
- But later if I comeback and select `option2`, click on `btn1` and hit save the state will hold
  `first name`, `last name` and `option2` with `btn1` pressed.
- after saving `option2` if i click `option1`, i can still see the `first & last name` filled
- I have attached the sample code, all the fields are picked up from Django application

***- the issue is, every ratio button options has its on number of components nested. how do toggle all the nested values of non selected options to null or default when the alternative option of the radio button is selected.***

```
// Radio_button_field.js
import React from "react";
import {Col, FormGroup, Input, Label, Row} from "reactstrap";

export default class RadioButtonField extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let radioValues = {}
        this.props.options.forEach((el) => {
            let val = false
            if (el.value === "true") {
                val = true
            }
            radioValues = {
                ...radioValues,
                [el.title]: val
            }
        })
        if (this.props.value != null && this.props.value !== "") {
            radioValues[this.props.value] = true
        }
        this.state = {
            [this.props.name]: radioValues
        }
    }

    toggleRadioButton = (key) => {
        let propName = this.props.name
        let newRadioValues = Object.assign(...Object.keys(this.state[propName]).map(k => ({[k]: false})))
        if (this.state[this.props.name][key] !== true) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                [propName]: {
                    ...newRadioValues,
                    [key]: !prevState[propName][key]
                }
            }))
        }
        this.props.handleChange(this.props.name, key);
    }

    render() {
        let options = this.props.options
        let colItems = [], rowItems = []
        for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 !== 0) {
                colItems.push(i)
                colItems = []
            } else if (i % 2 === 0) {
                colItems.push(i)
                rowItems.push({colItems})
            }
        }
        return <FormGroup>
            <Label for={this.props.name}>{this.props.label} {this.props.required ? '*' : null}
                {this.props.error ? <p className={'text-danger'} style={{
                    fontWeight: 'normal',
                    fontSize: 12
                }}>{this.props.errorMessage}</p> : null}</Label>

            {rowItems.map((rowItem, rowIdx) =>
                <Row key={rowIdx}>
                    {rowItem.colItems.map((colItem, colIdx) =>
                        <Col key={colIdx}>
                            <Label className={'radio-button-label ' +
                            (this.state[this.props.name][options[colItem].title] ? 'radio-button-label-checked'
                                : '')} for={options[colItem].name}
                                   onClick={() => this.toggleRadioButton(options[colItem].title)}>{options[colItem].title}</Label>
                            <Input type="radio"
                                   name={options[colItem].name} id={options[colItem].name}
                                   style={{visibility: "hidden"}}/>
                        </Col>
                    )}
                </Row>
            )}
        </FormGroup>
    }
// handle change method where name will be Radio button name, value will be options of radio button
    handleChange = (name, value) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            currStepResponses: {
                ...prevState.currStepResponses,
                [name]: value
            },
            dataSaved: false,
        }))
    }
// implementation page 
const myRadioButtonTag = <RadioButtonField name={el['name']}
                   placeholder={el['placeholder']}
                   label={el['label']}
                   options={el['options']}// will get the ratio button options
                   handleChange={this.handleChange}
                   value={currStepResponses[el['name']]}
                   error={errorFields[el['name']]}
                   errorMessage={FormFieldsHandling[el['name']] !== undefined ?                                      
                   FormFieldsHandling[el['name']]['message'] : ''}
                   required={CompulsoryFields.includes(el['name'])}/>

<Row>{myRadioButtonTag} </Row>
```